# How to get the origin(in the screen) of a image that placed in the tableviewcell?

Tags: ios, image, uitableview

How to get the origin of a image that placed in the `UITableViewCell`?
The origin I mean is its origin that in the screen not inside the `UITableViewCell`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIView` has a couple of methods that are very useful for that kind of stuff, they start with `convertRect:...` and `convertPoint:...` and end with `fromView:` and `toView:`.

In your case, calling `convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:tableView` on the image view would return what you need.

These methods only work if both views are in the same view hierarchy.

Comment: I dont really understand . In fact I have image in the tableview cell  I want to know the origin of its in the scree when i press it.

Comment: Like CGRect testing = [uiimageview convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.table];??

Comment: `convertPoint` returns a point, `convertRect` returns a rect. You also need to call them on the image view object, not on the `UIImageView` class.